# How to count how often a Function was accessed?

Tags: python, function, count

So i have the Function Ball() for example. and in that Function i have imported a list with Ball names where i randomly choose one and return that name.
so i want to know how i can count how many times the Function was accessed.

i tried this:

```
def Ball():   
     counter = 0
     Ball_name = Ball.man
     Ball_name = random.choice(Ball_name)
     counter =  counter+1
 return Ball_name

 counter_1 = Ball(counter)
 print(counter_1)
```

but it didnt work. 
Thank you for all youre help i really.
But i dont want any answers which say, that i have to learn Python from the beging or something. 
I want real help because im really stressed because of that.
I cant use Global variables
THANK YOU

Comment: Declare `counter` outside the function. Read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/)

Comment: Using `global` should only happen if there is no other way. In this case I would use a class or look for a solution using a decorator.

Answer (score 2):

You can give your function an attribute, like `count`, and increment it every time the function is called.

```py
def Ball():
    if not hasattr(Ball, 'count'):
        Ball.count = 0
    Ball.count += 1

Ball()
print(Ball.count) # will print 1
Ball()
print(Ball.count) # will print 2
```

You can take a look at [PEP 232 -- Function Attributes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232) if you want to know more about it.

Comment: This is somewhat fragile, in that you aren't necessarily incrementing an attribute of the function; you're incrementing an attribute of whatever the global name `Ball` is currently bound to, which can be changed from the original function.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just one function where you want to count, then hacking in a function attribute will do the trick.

For a more general solution, you can use *decorators*:

```
def count(f):
    def f_with_counter(*args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(f_with_counter, 'count'):
            f_with_counter.count = 0
        f_with_counter.count += 1
    return f_with_counter

@count
def Ball():
    pass
    #whatever it is that Ball does

Ball()
print(Ball.count) # should print 1 just as in the example above
Ball()
print(Ball.count) # should print 2 now.
```